# Openconnect VPN throwing "Failed to read from SSL socket: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated" + More

Tags: vpn, raspberrypi, openconnect

These are my specs:

- Platform: Raspberry Pi 4
- Raspberry Pi version: 2021-05-07
- Anyconnect version: v8.02-1+deb10u1
- CLI launch command: `openconnect -v ***.***.172.2:4443`

Error output:

```
*****BEGIN ERROR OUTPUT    
POST https://***.***.172.2:4443/
Attempting to connect to server ***.***.172.2:4443
Connected to ***.***.172.2:4443
SSL negotiation with ***.***.172.2
Server certificate verify failed: certificate does not match hostname
Certificate from VPN server "***.***.172.2" failed verification.
Reason: certificate does not match hostname
To trust this server in future, perhaps add this to your command line:
    --servercert pin-sha256:*******************************************
Enter 'yes' to accept, 'no' to abort; anything else to view: yes
Connected to HTTPS on ***.***.172.2
Failed to read from SSL socket: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
Error fetching HTTPS response
GET https://***.***.172.2:4443/
Attempting to connect to server ***.***.172.2:4443
Connected to ***.***.172.2:4443
SSL negotiation with ***.***.172.2
Server certificate verify failed: certificate does not match hostname
Connected to HTTPS on ***.***.172.2
Failed to read from SSL socket: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
Error fetching HTTPS response
Failed to obtain WebVPN cookie
***END ERROR OUTPUT
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: From your post. Reason: certificate does not match hostname
To trust this server in future, perhaps add this to your command line:
    --servercert pin-sha256:*******************************************   Did you do as it suggested?